# PostgreSQL stored procedure does not allow to use SELECT INTO and throws error "INTO used with a command that cannot return data"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

This stored procedure simply inserts some values in a table, but it is giving me a real pain when I try to return a type just to show the inserted values. I have declared a variable (report_tab) and the type (report_building_style_type) I want to return, but if I try to fill it via SELECT INTO (no matter in which select I try it) it would throw the "Error: INTO used with a command that cannot return data".

I have tried to figure out what this means and how to solve it, even checked some previus stackoverflow related questions, but cannot actually find the answer.

This is my code so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_report_building_style(p_year integer)
RETURNS report_building_style_type
AS $$
DECLARE
found_bld building.id_building%TYPE;
report_tab report_building_style_type;
BEGIN
FOR found_bld IN
SELECT m.id_building into report_tab.t_id_building
FROM building m
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM m.birth) = p_year
LOOP
INSERT INTO report_building_style
SELECT INTO 
report_tab.t_id_building,
report_tab.t_ style ,
report_tab.t_ num_firms,
report_tab.t_ stages,
report_tab.t_average_building_height
DISTINCT 
T1.id_building, 
T1.style, 
T2.num_firms, 
T3.num_stages, 
T4.num_built_buildings, 
T5.average_building_height
FROM 
(SELECT 
x0.id_building, 
firm.style
FROM firm, 
(SELECT building.name, building.id_building, id_firm 
FROM building 
INNER JOIN member
ON building.id_building = member.id_building
WHERE building.id_building = found_bld
GROUP BY building.id_building, building.name, id_firm) as x0
WHERE firm.id_firm = x0.id_firm
GROUP BY x0.id_building, x0.name, x0.id_firm, firm.style) AS T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT x1.id_building, x1.name, COUNT(*) AS num_firms 
FROM (SELECT building.name, building.id_building, id_firm
FROM building
INNER JOIN member
ON building.id_building = member.id_building
WHERE building.id_building = found_bld
GROUP BY member.id_firm, building.id_building, building.name) as x1
GROUP BY x1.id_building, x1.name) AS T2
ON T1.id_building = T2.id_building
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT x2.id_building, x2.name, COUNT(*) AS num_stages
FROM (SELECT building.name, building.id_building, member.id_firm
FROM building
INNER JOIN member
ON building.id_building = member.id_building
INNER JOIN stage
ON stage.id_firm = member.id_firm
WHERE building.id_building = found_bld   
GROUP BY stage.id_stage, member.id_firm, building.id_building, building.name) as x2
GROUP BY x2.id_building, x2.name
ORDER BY x2.id_building) AS T3
ON T3.id_building = T2.id_building
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT x3.id_building, x3.name, COUNT(*) AS num_built_buildings
FROM (SELECT building.name, building.id_building
FROM building
INNER JOIN architect
ON architect.id_building = building.id_building
WHERE building.id_building = found_bld   
GROUP BY architect.id_building, building.id_building, building.name) as x3
GROUP BY x3.id_building, x3.name
ORDER BY x3.id_building) AS T4
ON T4.id_building = T3.id_building
INNER JOIN 
(select b.id_building, SUM (b.height)/COUNT (*) AS average_building_height 
from (SELECT building.name, building.id_building, building.height, SUM(building.height) AS building_height
FROM building
INNER JOIN architect
ON architect.id_building = building.id_building
INNER JOIN building
ON building.id_building = architect.id_building
WHERE building.id_building = found_bld  
GROUP BY building.id_building, building.name, building.duration, architect.id_building
ORDER BY building.id_building) as b
group by id_building) AS T5 
ON T5.id_building = T3.id_building
ORDER BY T1.id_building
ON CONFLICT (id_building, style) 
DO UPDATE SET 
style = excluded.style,
num_firms = excluded.num_firms,
num_stages = excluded.num_stages,
num_built_buildings = excluded.num_built_buildings,
average_building_height = excluded.average_building_height;
return report_tab;
END LOOP;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! ([mcve])

Comment: This `FOR found_bld IN SELECT m.id_building into report_tab.t_id_building` does not make any sense. Lose the `into report_tab.t_id_building` part.

Comment: Many thanks @Adrian Klaver. But that is the question, if I lose the into report part, how can i fill the report_tab so I can return the results?

Comment: You are not doing  `select into report_tab` you are doing `select into report_tab.t_id_building` with `m.id_building`. Just use `m.id_building`. Later on you run into a similar priblem in the `INSERT INTO`. I would lose that portion of the query and just do the `SELECT INTO report_tab.*` using the data from that long `SELECT` query. Then use the `report_tab.*` values to do the `INSERT INTO`

Comment: Wow, thanks @Adrian Klaver that is brillant and works fine!